# Using Bigarray in Ocaml

Tags: numpy, ocaml

I am new to Ocaml and I am trying to use he https://github.com/LaurentMazare/npy-ocaml library. For now I just want to open file I created in python through:

```
In [1]: import numpy as np

In [2]: a = np.arange(10)

In [3]: np.save("bla.npy", a)
```

I already managed to match the type of the array, but I failed to read any value from it:

```
let Npy.P rarray = Npy.read_mmap "bla.npy" ~shared:false in
 begin
    match Bigarray.Genarray.layout rarray with
    | Bigarray.Fortran_layout -> assert false
    | Bigarray.C_layout ->
      match Bigarray.Genarray.kind rarray with
      | Bigarray.Float32 -> print_string "F32"
      | Bigarray.Float64 -> print_string "F64"
      | Bigarray.Int32 -> print_string "I32" 
      | Bigarray.Int64 -> print_int (rarray.get [1])
      | _ -> print_string "oohh"
 end;;

print_endline " ";;
```

How can I access values on a Bigarray?

Comment: What output do you see when you run this code?

Comment: I get: File "test.ml", line 10, characters 44-47:
Error: Unbound record field get

Comment: You're using a kind of OO notation. In OCaml, the functions come from the module not the object itself: `Bigarray.Array1.get rarray 1` is closer to what you want.

Answer (score 0):

To access values of `Genarray` you may either use a [Genarray.get](http://caml.inria.fr/pub/docs/manual-ocaml/libref/Bigarray.Genarray.html#VALget) function that accepts an array of indices, e.g., `Genarray.get rarray [|1;2;3;4|]`, or a curly bracket subscription syntax, e.g., `rarray.{1,2,3,4}`.

Also, it looks like that your array is one-dimensional, so you need to use the `Npy.P1` constructor, then you may access the elements using either the [Array1.get](http://caml.inria.fr/pub/docs/manual-ocaml/libref/Bigarray.Array1.html#VALget) function, or a subscription syntax, e.g., `rarray.{0}`

Comment: If I try rarray.{0} I get:
File "test.ml", line 10, characters 36-42:
Error: This expression has type ($P, $P1, $P2) Bigarray.Genarray.t
       but an expression was expected of type ('a, 'b, 'c) Bigarray.Array1.t
make: *** [Makefile:2: all] Error 2

Comment: Because you need to extract with Npy.P1, not Npy.P.

Comment: If I try let `Npy.P1 rarray = Npy.read_mmap "bla.npy" ~shared:false` I get `Error: The constructor Npy.P1 belongs to the variant type Npy.packed_array1
       but a constructor was expected belonging to the variant type
         Npy.packed_array
`

Comment: Yeah, sorry, you also need to use `Npy.read_mmap1` to get an `Npy.packed_array1` type array. This library is overcomplicated :(

Answer (score 0):

This particular library seems to be missing some utility functions to extract a well-typed bigarray from an untyped packed array.

You can write such an extraction function as

```
let extract_c_int64 (P a) =
  match Genarray.layout a with 
  | Fortran_layout -> None
  | C_layout -> 
     match Genarray.kind a with
     | Int64 -> Some (a:(float,float64_elt,c_layout) Genarray.t)
     | _ -> None;;
```

This function will then return `Some a` if the dynamically typed array was really an array of int64 with a C layout and `None` otherwise. One possible use would be

```
let a =
   match extract_c_float64 with
   | None -> raise (Invalid_argument "wrong type of array")
   | Some a-> a
```

Once the array extracted, it would become much easier to manipulate the array. For instance, reading can be done with `let a1111= a.{1,1,1,1}` and writing to the array is quite similar `a.{1,2,4,5} <- 2L`.